# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' even after including FormsModule in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

Exactly as the title says. My code looks like this

```
<h1>Add New Product</h1>
<div>ID: </div>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pid" name="pid"/>
<div>Name: </div>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pname" name="pname"/>
<div>Description: </div>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pdesc" name="pdesc" />
<div>Price: </div>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="price" name="price" />
<div>
  <button >Sumbit</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button >Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And it's producing the error
"Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'."

Even though my app.module.ts looks like this

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list/product-list.component';
import { EditProductComponent } from './edit-product/edit-product.component';
import { AddProductComponent } from './add-product/add-product.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    EditProductComponent,
    AddProductComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgModule,
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There is FormsModule in the header, in the imports, and in the exports

Comment: Is `AppModule` the root module of your Angular App? If yes, remove the `exports` part.

Comment: What is the problem? What is the error? If it is wrong, what is the error message? Please send a photo or text of the error as well. Please ask the full question so that it can be answered.